# Why does my perpetual CMBR rocket ship not work? Why does the CMBR have infinite energy?

Tags: general-relativity, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, rocket-science, cosmic-microwave-background

Take a spaceship and accelerate it to 99.947% the speed of light, effectively blueshifting the Cosmic Microwave Background (CMB) from 1.9mm to 500nm, turning the CMB to a harvestable source of energy. Line the front of the craft which has an annular extrusion shape with solar cells. Install an extremely efficient linear accelerator that accelerates hydrogen in the center, which only uses hydrogen found along the way.

Theoretically, ignoring relativistic damage, by directly harvesting from the CMB (and other light sources), this craft should be able to accelerate forever. Even past the point of complete blackout of the universe and cold death (if such a thing exists). Given the CMB is everywhere, and the universe is infinite, therefore the CMB is infinite, and contains infinite energy, as long as the spacecraft could keep accelerating faster than the CMB is relativistically aging, it should be able to keep on accelerating.

I did a little engineering just to see how this plays out. We take the normally accepted heat of the CMB at 2.7k, then blue shift it, .999c, find the new temperature, then use Stefan to derive the intensity of line. Using something like 10% total system efficiency, and a Vasimr like drive with a 5000 second impulse, you end up net positive. You get to extremely high intensities at high fractions of C, which only increases the power available. In addition, the radiation pressure never comes close to the propulsion. I guess, maybe at some point aerodynamics will prevent you from moving faster.

Here is the other weird thing though, I don't think you can "Consume" the CMB. So even if the universe was finite, and you just kept going circles around the universe... its not like you would end up with "bald patches" of CMB right? We see particles hurdled across fast enough to interact with the CMB all the time, but yet don't necessarily see degradation in the CMB.

What's going on here? While really impossible, the CMB looks like an infinite source of energy, one that is decaying, but keeps on giving if you can go fast enough.

**** This post is not really about the rocket, but the CMB, and how it's being abused in this case. Why does it look like the CMB contains infinite amounts of energy that you can't deplete.

***** I am not advocating I've found a new source of energy, just here to learn.

Comment: Does anything there matter, but whether you can "Consume" the CMB? If you dropped all else, what would be lost?

Answer (score 24):

So this works even a little bit better than you think because of something called relativistic beaming, which would cause all of the CMB radiation to be coming at you from a point “ahead of you”—i.e. in the direction you are accelerating. This also potentially allows you to escape the low-velocity problem that you don't have access to a reservoir with lower temperature than the CMBR, and thus can't harvest the energy: the side that sees the CMBR redshifted, sees a lower intensity of radiation too, giving a way to radiatively cool beneath the CMBR temperature floor.

BUT, this also presents a severe problem to the idea, which is that to harvest an energy E from that direction, you must also absorb its momentum $-E/c$, which will slow you down. Relativistic beaming implies that there is no way to redirect this momentum to be coming at you from behind or the side.

You wish to capture a relativistic hydrogen atom moving backwards relative to your intended thrust, and then accelerate it to move even faster backwards, with the energy $E$ that you have harvested. So it had energy $\gamma m c^2$ and you now wish to send it out with energy $(\gamma +\delta \gamma) mc^2$, where $\delta \gamma = E/(mc^2).$

Now relativistic momentum goes like $mc~\gamma \beta$ and there is a useful identity in terms of rapidities where $$\begin{align}\gamma &=\cosh\phi,\\\gamma\beta&=\sinh\phi=\pm\sqrt{\cosh^2\phi-1}\\&=\pm\sqrt{\gamma^2-1}.\end{align}$$This can eventually be coaxed into saying that for this small change in $\gamma$ induced by adding the energy $E$, you can create a momentum
$$\delta p=\frac{E}{v}.$$
So, you had to absorb a small momentum $E/c$ to create a potentially larger momentum ~ $E/v$. Except, as you go faster, these hydrogen atoms have $v\approx c$ and the momentum that you generate is no bigger than the momentum you already had absorbed!

So you can't beat the thermal inefficiencies at non-relativistic speeds, but you also can't asymptotically beat the practical conversion efficiencies at high speeds because your ability to extract momentum from the particles is only good if they have been “coming along for the ride”—i.e. co-moving with you all this time. Particles that are at rest relative to the CMB, just don't give you very much momentum if you fling them backwards even harder than they are already going.

Comment: Thank you for the long response! What do you think is happening to the CMB during all this. Are you really absorbing it? Is it really just an infinite energy source, even if it doesn't work in my rocket? That is the part that is intriguing. It doesn't seem like you can "use it up."

Comment: Yeah, you're really absorbing CMB. It is a finite resource with a well defined flux through the cross section of your spaceship. Similarly if you used a solar sail to brake against the CMB, those photons have been redirected. I think that fo a distant observer it would seem like you were using your kinetic energy to convert a bunch of CMB to a longer wavelength and meanwhile propel a weak hydrogen jet. (Note that the thermal radiation that you emit gets also beamed into the “forward” direction as seen from a distant observer, but I think it is still redshifted?

Comment: A blue-shifted CMB seems to signify a global reference velocity??!! What???? We need some experts in here. This is getting weird. Some premise of what I'm doing is definitely broken. This would mean that based on where you are, and which direction you are going the CMB temperature is different.

Comment: As hydrogen's speed approaches c, but never reaches c, the net thrust approaches zero but never reaches zero. Right? (Net thrust is absorbed momentum + thrust of the motor)

Comment: Even on Earth we see a very slight anisotrophy in the CMB due to our proper motion. This rocket simply magnifies that effect.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir that is fascinating. So, is there a universal reference frame effectively? Velocity is not just a number; instead, the universe "knows" how fast you are going. I wonder how much thrust you would need to get the CMB completely isotropic, or if you could tell?

Comment: Yeah you can just read Wikipedia about it, “From the CMB data, it is seen that the Sun appears to be moving at 368±2 km/s relative to the reference frame of the CMB (also called the CMB rest frame, or the frame of reference in which there is no motion through the CMB). The Local Group — the galaxy group that includes our own Milky Way galaxy — appears to be moving at 627±22 km/s in the direction of galactic longitude ℓ = 276°±3°, b = 30°±3°.[86][13]”

Comment: @TravisR No, CMB is not a reference frame in the sense it does not relate to particular position in space. You can be at rest in regard to CMB wherever you like and no place is better than any other place.

Comment: @TravisR Relativity does not say there are no special frames, it says there are no special frames *where the laws of physics are different*. There is in fact a privileged frame in which one is at rest with respect to the CMB. But you could do your physics in any other frame just as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your knowledgeable responses. I'm so glad I posted this question; I learned some new things about physics and, hopefully, drug a couple more with me. :)

Answer (score 11):

The CMBR will decelerate your vehicle, since the blueshifted photons in front of you give you more momentum in the opposite direction of motion than the redshifted photons from behind give you momentum in direction of motion, so your mechanism won't work due to the energy/momentum-laws. By the same principle a solar sail can only be pushed, but not pulled by photons.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151331/discussion-on-answer-by-yukterez-why-does-my-perpetual-cmbr-rocket-ship-not-work); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Your idea pretty much relates to sailing with no wind and in still water, using some initial momentum. This does not work in the long term.

On the other hand, sailing with some wind is pretty much possible in any direction (even against the wind) and with virtually any speed (subject to efficiency limitations, but trivially more than the speed of the wind).

Comment: @water is the hydrogen, wind is the light

Answer (score 2):

> In addition, the radiation pressure never comes close to the propulsion.

Unfortunately, this is a mistake. The issue is that the propulsion depends on the speed of the hydrogen, and for relativistic velocities the propulsion becomes very small and approaches the radiation pressure even for perfectly ideal drives.

To see why this is so, first start with Newtonian mechanics. The engine will add an amount of energy $\delta E$ to a passing bit of reaction mass $m$ which is already moving at velocity $v$ to make it move a little faster $v+\delta v$ giving an amount of momentum $\delta p$ for thrust. Conservation of energy and momentum give us $$\frac{1}{2}m(v+\delta v)^2 - \frac{1}{2}mv^2=\delta E$$$$m(v+\delta v)-mv=\delta p$$ We can eliminate $\delta v$ and solve for $\delta p$ to get $$\delta p=\sqrt{2\ \delta E \ m+v^2 m^2}-vm$$ This gets smaller as $v$ gets larger.

The relativistic case shows the same trend but is messier. In this case the reaction mass moving at $v$ starts with a four-momentum $(E/c,\vec p)=(\gamma m c, \gamma m v)$ where $1/\gamma=\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. Then we use the Minkowski norm to calculate $$m^2 c^2 = \left(\gamma m c + \delta E/c \right)^2 - \left(\gamma m v + \delta p \right)^2 $$ which can be solved to obtain $$\delta p =\sqrt{\frac{\delta E^2}{c^2}+ 2\gamma \ \delta E\ m + (\gamma^2-1)m^2 c^2}-\gamma m v $$ Now, although this is messy, it simplifies substantially if $\delta E$ is very small. In that case we can do a series expansion around $\delta E=0$ to obtain $$\delta p \approx \frac{\delta E}{v}$$ If $\delta E$ is not small then $\delta p$ is even smaller than the approximation. So as $v$ increases, the thrust for a given small amount of energy decreases. As $v$ approaches $c$, in SI units $\delta E$ is divided by a number on the order of 300 million.

Now, $\delta E$ is the energy provided to the reaction mass. To produce that amount of energy required the absorption of an amount of energy $\delta E/\xi$ where $0<\xi<1$ is the efficiency of the system from absorption of the energy in the solar panels to the delivery of the energy to the reaction mass. So the momentum lost from absorbing the radiation is $\delta E/(\xi c)$. So the net thrust is $$\delta p_{net} \lt \left(\frac{1}{v}-\frac{1}{\xi c} \right) \delta E $$ where the $\lt$ indicates that we are neglecting other sources of drag, such as reaction mass that collides with the ship instead of being accelerated by $\delta E$. The term on the right goes to $0$ at $v=\xi c$, so that is a hard limit on the maximum speed of this type of propulsion.

> Take a spaceship and accelerate it to 99.947% the speed of light

So this would already require zero drag from other sources and a 99.947% efficient system including everything from the solar panels to the reaction mass.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to take photons coming in from the front and mostly in the direction opposite of travel, and use their energy to propel your craft forward. From a momentum perspective, you'd need all of those photons to exit the interaction with your spacecraft more quickly than they came in (and backwards). This is really close to how jet engines work - they take incoming air, heat it up and then shoot it out the back much faster than it entered. Your perpetual CMBR rocket ship, however, will work just as well as a jet engine with no fuel. **Energy and momentum are always conserved.**

You've shared results but not calculations, so I can't be sure, but I would guess that you didn't factor in the (normally too small to matter) change in momentum for your spacecraft when it catches the photons. For future reference, not sharing calculations is an extremely common trope for perpetual motion claimants. If that's an honest mistake, just swallow your pride and put the calculations into the question - we all make mistakes. If it's not, kudos: we might all die of old age before your conjecture's testable.

For an interesting read on how cosmic microwave background radiation actually spacecraft, check out this [article](https://www.technologyreview.com/2015/03/24/73189/spacecraft-traveling-close-to-light-speed-should-be-visible-with-current-technology-say/) based on this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05845.pdf) which shows that the CMB actually gives spacecraft a galactic speed limit.

EDIT:

Apparently, OP wants to take the incoming photons and keep them, and then use their energy to propel stray hydrogen out the back. It is not clear if the stray hydrogen had any momentum when it was acquired.

It is tempting to believe that the apparently limitless energy of the CMB is an anomaly in physics - that there are no other situations where objects are surrounded by virtually boundless amounts of energy. This is plainly false. The question is never about how much energy is around, it's always how much *useful* energy is around. Photosynthesis and photovoltaics only work when there's a hot side and a cold side. Sails only work when one side has more pressure than the other. Extracting electricity from heat requires a temperature difference. The CMB is no different, no matter the speed.

Comment: We aren't shooting photons out the back, we are using photons to generate electricity and take advantage of the inequality between radiation pressure (I/C vs photovoltaic cells I*e (where e is usually 10%-40%). We use stray hydrogen as the propellant, as stated above. 

It is sound; how fast it could actually go is quite a difficult and useless calculation. Its a thought experiment exploring the CMBR.

Comment: So, by analogy, it'd be like adding radon (or a similarly heavy gas) to a jet engine's exhaust? Where does the "stray hydrogen" come from? The article is quite good. And the paper is even better if you can manage it. Also, I'd love to see your calculations.

Comment: No, its interstellar \ intergalactic hydrogen that fills all of space. The premise is pretty simple, though. The CMBR has an accepted temperature of 2.7k. It is blue-shifted using Lorentz. Then a new temperature is derived using the blueshift frequency. The intensity is then recalculated using Stefan Blackbody. Then you multiply this intensity against the respective equations, where radiation pressure is I/C and total conversion from energy to force is I*e. It's not like it's super complicated to replicate...

Comment: Photovoltaic cells do not require a cold side, as found in any photovoltaic equation I've found, but in this case, there is a cold side because while we have blue-shifted the CMB, we have red-shifted what is behind us by the same margin.

Comment: Put the math in your question. Be explicit. You don't want people to think you're a [crank](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Crank). As for the specifics you've provided, your conclusion goes against freshmen physics and thermodynamics. I don't have to try to understand whatever it is you're half-heartedly trying to explain. You're using really common tactics that other [perpetual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) motion [believers](https://skullsinthestars.com/2010/03/10/perpetual-motion-nonsense-for-over-100-years/) use.

Comment: Also, did you read the article and paper? You'll get both some vindication and some knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151353/discussion-between-travis-r-and-user121330).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are not taking into account the fact that your fuel, intergalactic hydrogen, will be travelling towards you with a speed of .99947 c.   A more common term for a proton (hydrogen nucleus) moving at that speed is [cosmic ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray).  The energy distribution of cosmic rays peaks at 300 MeV, each proton here would be about 28 GeV, pretty high-energy.  If your space ship was the size of a school bus travelling with the shortest cross-section, you would have about 81 billion of these cosmic rays hitting your ship each second of ship time.

When these cosmic rays interact with any matter in your ship, they would annihilate it and create a shower of other particles.  There isn't a way to capture that energy, and if there were it would still in general have momentum in the opposite direction of your flight path.   You need to invent some way to  provide an extra push in the direction the proton is already moving without it interacting with your ship.

The LHC can reach up to 7 TeV by accelerating streams of protons like you will be receiving up to 0.9999991 c, but that uses enormous amounts of energy and requires a 27km circular tube for a very small beam of protons.   Linear accelerators might be able to provide some push in the existing direction of travel to give you a kind of thrust, but the extra impetus provided would be very small, and would have to overcome any cross-section of your ship that wasn't open for the flow and acceleration of those protons.   Linear accelerators currently work at energies of less than 100 MeV.  If you had some kind of shielding or scoop to funnel the protons into your accelerators, that action of altering their trajectory would slow your ship down.

What you are thinking of is like a speed-boat powered by scooping up a thimble of water and throwing it out the back to provide thrust.  The act of scooping it up slows your ship down more than any thrust you can gain by throwing it out the back, and has to overcome the resistance of the rest of your ship.