In a fast moving space ship, can you harvest energy from the radiation background?
In a fast moving space ship (let's say a meaningful portion of c), radiation coming from the front is blue-shifted, while the one coming from behind is red-shifted. Meaning the part of the universe ahead is hotter than the one behind - can this difference be used to power a heat engine?

Consider an analogous situation: an aircraft fitted with an air-powered turbine.

I remember a very similar question which seems quite relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/800263/23615.

@Triatticus That seems like exactly the same question, maybe a bit better thought out. Thanks.
